# How to apply rolling function backwards with multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

Given this simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I'm trying to perform the following calculations:

1. Add three columns called B1, C2 and D2 filled with **NaN** by default.
2. Check the next 5 rows of column A one by one, the first one that is greater than 20, then columns B1, C2 and D2 will be filled with the content of B, C and D columns of that specific row.
3. If none of those next 5 rows of column A are smaller than 20, then columns B1, C2 and D2 will remain as **NaN**.

I came up with this approach:

```
def check_thresh(ser):
    dft = df.loc[ser.index]
    
    for _, row in dft.iterrows():
        if row['A'] > 20:
            return np.array([row['B'], row['C'], row['D']])
        
    return np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

rol = df['A'].rolling(window=5)
df[['B1', 'C1', 'D1']] = rol.apply(check_thresh, raw=False)
```

However, I face the following issues:

1. It checks the *previous* 5 rows, not the *next* 5 rows.
2. The performance is quite slow, and I have to work with a large dataset.
3. It returns the following error: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` when applying the rolling function to the new columns.

What's the problem with my approach? Do you know any better one to handle this scenario?

Comment: What an ugly problem! However, I think 5 rows is still (just) within the realm of hard-coding using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). That way, you can create new columns with each of the forward-looking rows and vectorize this

Comment: In other words, each row also has columns that tell it what the value of the next row, and the next next row, is.... and so forth

Comment: Also, I think your current approach is O(N^2) at best. It looks like you have to iterate the whole df for every row.

Comment: I can't run your example btw. `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` with `df[['B1', 'C1', 'D1']] = rol.apply(check_thresh, raw=False)`

Comment: @harrison4 Please edit your question and include your expected output for the given sample of data. One more thing as the data is generated using random sample you should add a random seed before generating the data so that we could be able to reproduce your dataframe.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma is right. Please give an example and its expected result. (Be kind with my answer :-)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this implementation is optimized or even if it is correct because I did not fully understand the question and do not have an example of expected output.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

WINDOWSIZE = 5
THRESHOLD = 20

# Equivalent to pd.rolling
m = sliding_window_view(df, (WINDOWSIZE, len(df.columns))).squeeze().astype(float)

# Extract 'A' column
A = m[:, :, 0]

# Get the first index whose value > THRESHOLD
argm = np.argmax(A > THRESHOLD, axis=1)

# True if all values <= THRESHOLD
amin = np.amin(A <= THRESHOLD, axis=1)

# Select rows in original array m
r = np.take_along_axis(m, argm[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis], axis=1).squeeze()
r[amin] = np.nan
```

Example:

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
5  20  21  22  23
6  24  25  26  27
7  28  29  30  31
8  32  33  34  35
9  36  37  38  39
```

```
# df1 = pd.DataFrame(A).rename(columns='A{}'.format).assign(argm=argm, amin=amin)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['A', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'])

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='columns')
     A0    A1    A2    A3    A4  argm   amin     A    B1    C1    D1
0   0.0   4.0   8.0  12.0  16.0     0   True   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   4.0   8.0  12.0  16.0  20.0     0   True   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   8.0  12.0  16.0  20.0  24.0     4  False  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0
3  12.0  16.0  20.0  24.0  28.0     3  False  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0
4  16.0  20.0  24.0  28.0  32.0     2  False  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0
5  20.0  24.0  28.0  32.0  36.0     1  False  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0
```

*Note: the length of the final dataframe is `len(df) - WINDOWSIZE + 1`*

Comment: Great answer! Really liked the idea.